# SecItemCopyMatching condition fails in Keychainitemwrapper class so unable to retrieve saved value in keychain

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, keychain, keychainitemwrapper

I have 2 applications. One is in appstore and the other one I am working currently. Using my first app I have saved a string in keychain and now using the second app I am trying to retrieve the same value. But every time the below condition fails. So I am unable to retrieve the saved value.

```
if (! SecItemCopyMatching((CFDictionaryRef)tempQuery, (CFTypeRef *)&outDictionary) == noErr)
```

Please let me know where am I doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you cannot share keychain between an app store app and an app you are currently developing. The entitlements are different for the apps signed with distribution profile (which is the case for an app store app) and those signed with a development profile.

Comment: I am planning to release next version of the same app to appstore. In this case do we have an option to access the data stored in keychainw

Comment: You would have the current version of the same app that is signed with developer profile - couldn't you use that?